# To redirect output to screen instead of csv file

Tags: shell, unix, csv, while-loop, echo

There is a shell script I am running which reads some columns fron the file and write it to the csv file. Like the compilation of the records from the two files.

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read -r a1 a2 a3  && read -r b1 b2 b3  <&3; do
echo $a2 $a3 $b1 $b2
done <account_info.csv 3<Error.csv > output.csv
echo "extraction is done"
```

Now after the compilation is complete in the output.csv file I want to print the message on the screen "extraction is done". But instead the message is getting printed in the file output.csv. Is there any reason of this behaviour of the output of the ">" operator.
Please help to get output message to the screen.

Comment: There is no reason for the message _extraction is done_ to be written to the file.  Is this your complete script?

Comment: how did you run the script. like this ? `./script.sh > output.csv`

Comment: test.ksh is the name of the script I am running. I have created a .ksh file and running it in the putty. Its happening and I am feeling helpless.

Comment: You are aware that you are reading a1, a2 and a3 from stdin and the "b" values from Error.csv, correct?  With "ksh" you should be able to use "read -u3" and avoid the redirection and also make clear you know what you are doing.  Anyway, it does look like you've redirected the script's stdout, so either don't do that or redirect the echo to /dev/tty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works:

```
#!/bin/ksh
IFS=','
while read -r a1 a2 a3 && read -r b1 b2 b3 <&3
do
  echo "${a2},${a3},${b1},${b2}"
done < a.csv  3< b.csv > output.csv
echo 'extraction is done'
```

Test files:

```
$ cat a.csv
a1,a2,a3
$ cat b.csv
b1,b2,b3
```

Run:

```
$ ./test.ksh
extraction is done
$ cat output.csv
a2,a3,b1,b2
```

ksh:

```
$ ksh --version
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-02-29
```